# Show scheduled posts in archive page

Tags: loop, archives, post-status

I'd like my archive.php page's daily view (is_day) to display scheduled posts (post_status=future). For example, if I go to mysite.com/2011/05/20 I would see all posts scheduled to appear on May 20.

The archive page's loop starts with:

```
if ( have_posts() )
the_post();
```

and ends with:

```
rewind_posts();
get_template_part( 'loop', 'archive' );
```

Do I need to make a second loop, or can I modify this single loop to show scheduled posts? If so, how? Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Keep things simple - leave your archive templates alone and place this in your `functions.php`;

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $wp_query ) {
    global $wp_post_statuses;

    if (
        ! empty( $wp_post_statuses['future'] ) &&
        ! is_admin() &&
        $wp_query->is_main_query() && (
            $wp_query->is_date() ||
            $wp_query->is_single()
        )
    ) {
        $wp_post_statuses['future']->public = true;
    }
});
```

Essentially, it says;

> If we're on a date archive, or viewing a single post, make future posts publicly visible.

As a result, WordPress behaves normally when you view archives for any given date, except now it also includes posts 'from the future'!.

Comment: I found this to be the most elegant of several solutions I found, thanks!