# Only show posts with date of today or in the future (i.e don't show past posts)?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, loop

Is it possible to only show posts that have todays date or in the future? I don't want to show any posts that are in the past.

Also, I want the list to show posts that have a date in the future as in the CMS it shows as scheduled.

Here's my loop:

```
<div class="news-content" style="background-color:#feefe7!IMPORTANT;">
  <div class="page-title-content">
    <h2><?php echo the_title(); ?></h2>
  </div>
  <div class="news-content-inner">
    <?php $portfolioloop = new WP_Query(array(
    'paged'          => get_query_var('paged'),
    'post_type'      => 'news',
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'tax_query'      => array(
        array(
        'taxonomy' => 'news',
        'field'    => 'id',
        'terms'    => 51,
        ),
        ),
    )); ?>
    <?php while ( $portfolioloop->have_posts() ) : $portfolioloop->the_post(); ?>
    <div class="news-item" onClick="location.href='<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>'">
      <h2><a style="color:#F45B11!IMPORTANT;" href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo the_time('d.m.Y'); ?> / <?php echo the_title(); ?></a></h2>
      <p class="news-page">
        <?php if (get_field('description') != "") { ?>
        <?php echo the_field('description'); ?>
        <?php } else { 
        $newscontent = get_the_content();
        $newscontent_str = strip_tags($newscontent, '');
        echo substr($newscontent_str,0,250) . "…";
        } ?>
      </p>
    </div>
    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
    <p class="news-page" style="font-size:12px!IMPORTANT;"><?php echo $portfolioloop->post_count; ?> opportunities</p>
    <?php if (function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) {
    wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $portfolioloop ) ); } ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't believe I didn't see this sooner, simply solved it with this in the query:

`'post_status'   => 'future'`

So once published it just disappears from the list.

Answer (score 0):

As described [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Time_Parameters), you could add an additional filter to your query.

```
// Create a new filtering function that will add our where clause to the query
function filter_where( $where = '' ) {
    $where .= " AND DATE(post_date) >= DATE(NOW())";
    return $where;
}

add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
$query = new WP_Query( $query_string );
remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
```

In your case that means the following:

```
<?php
 // Create a new filtering function that will add our where clause to the query
 function filter_where( $where = '' ) {
    $where .= " AND DATE(post_date) >= DATE(NOW())";
    return $where;
 }

 add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
 $portfolioloop = new WP_Query(array(
    'paged'          => get_query_var('paged'),
    'post_type'      => 'news',
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'tax_query'      => array(
        array(
        'taxonomy' => 'news',
        'field'    => 'id',
        'terms'    => 51,
        ),
        ),
    )); 
 remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
?>
```

Comment: Ok thanks. I put that in my template and it removed the past posts but how can I get round showing posts in the future?

Comment: In this question you can find a solution to include also the future posts: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16794/show-scheduled-posts-in-archive-page

Answer (score -3):

```
$query = new WP_Query('m>='.time());
if($query->have_posts()):
while($query->have_posts()):
$query->the_post();
endwhile
endif;
```

Comment: How would I incorporate this into my current code?

Comment: As far as I'm aware `m` isn't a query variable